# Getting a list of dates between two dates in java different results

Tags: java, jodatime

For some reasons using `plusDays(1)` doesnt give me the correct answer. It increments the results instead by 1. What to change to make this code below work properly. Removing plusDays(1) doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong here.

It should output

```
September 13, 2016
September 14, 2016
September 15, 2016
```

and not

```
September 14, 2016
September 15, 2016 
September 16, 2016
```

Code:

```
String startDate = "2016-09-13";
String endDate = "2016-09-15";
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(endDate);
List<LocalDate> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();

while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
    totalDates.add(start);
    start = start.plusDays(1);

    Milestones modelMilestones = new Milestones();
    modelMilestones .setMilestone(start.toString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
    mDataList.add(modelMilestones);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: You're calling `toString` *after* calling `plusDays`. Just don't do that - move the `start = start.plusDays(1);` to be the last line in the loop.

Comment: Side note. Your `totalDates` will contain several reference to same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this once:

```
while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
                totalDates.add(start);
                Milestones modelMilestones = new Milestones();
                modelMilestones .setMilestone(start.toString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
                mDataList.add(modelMilestones);

                start = start.plusDays(1);
            }
```